# Strapi - Update Additional Fields on User Model

Tags: rest, nuxt.js, strapi

Problem Statement: Able to register user but unable to update customFields on same model in single request. Detail explanation below.

I have added additional fields to UserModel on Strapi. UserModel Attached
[image]

I am building a front end using Nuxt, where admin user can create new users who can access the website. This is not Regular Signup, This is User getting created by admin of the site. I guess even a regular signup  I would face this issue. 
Admin has all the rights to crud users.

When I submit the form I am getting Forbidden error. Form Attached
[image]

Below is my code which handled the submit. I first register the user and based on the user id I try to update First Name and Last name.

```
handleSubmit() {
  if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
    this.loading = true
    // console.log(this.username, this.email, this.password)
    strapi
      .register(this.username, this.email, this.password)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        strapi
          .updateEntry('users', response.user.id, {
            firstName: this.firstname,
            lastname: this.lastname
          })
          .then(response => {
            this.loading = false
            this.$router.push('/users')
          })
          .catch(err => {
            this.loading = false
            // alert(err.message || 'An error occurred.')
            this.errorMessage = true
            this.errorMessageContent = err.message || 'An error occurred.'
          })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.loading = false
        // alert(err.message || 'An error occurred.')
        this.errorMessage = true
        this.errorMessageContent = err.message || 'An error occurred.'
      })
  }
}
```

Below is the console message.
[image]

Comment: The strapi.register operation also logs that user in so I think the second part of your operation would be sending a header as that user who it would seem doesn't have permission to update user. Maybe you can destroy that header and push your admin user one.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew1325. I will just check on that.

Comment: @Andrew1325 I need some help, if I destroy the token, how do I get the token back of admin?  is it possible to destroy the token of new user immediately or is there a flag to say don't store the token?

Comment: Because you are doing this as an admin creating a user you should be able to use `strapi.createEntry('users', ...` instead of `strapi.register`, and send all the user data in the one request. You will get the user back in the response without logging that user in.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew1325, I went ahead and used Axios in this case, which is as equal as strapi.createEntry()  But yes your first comment gave me think in right direction. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to `update` the additional user fields (using PUT method) or passing them to the back-end in the register process (using POST method) ?

If you want to update them, you have to do the following:

1. Adding fields to you user model (already done)
2. Make the `/update` endpoint available in the users-permissions configuration.
   See screenshot:
   [image]
3. Now you are able to use the PUT method on the endpoint `users/:id`, which you could do e.g. like this:[image]